# update column data if present else keep unmodified in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Mysql update all column data if present else keep unmodified in mysql query

i am having one column name 'gender' , it is having 4 records with 2 male and 1 female.
i have swap the gender using case in update query at that time the one record is blank which don't have gender but it is update as male according to writened query.

what i want which gender is blank it will not update it will remain as it is and where gender data is present it will swap gender.

thanks in advance

Comment: Andddd that query lies at?

Comment: update user set gender = case when gender = 'Male' then 'Female' else 'Male' end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this one

`update user set gender = case when gender = 'Male' then 'Female' when gender='Female' then 'Male' else '' end`

Comment: it's working fine thanks for info , but it's not a generic solution if we take another scenario it won't work like data is 'test' in gender field , in that case how to check the data and unchanged ...

Comment: didn't get you,please elaborate a little.

Comment: let's take one table user having two fields id & city. 

Table name : user

Id     City
1      pune,mumbai
2      hyderabad,pune
3      solapur
4      jammu,mumbai

Here i want to update semicoln(;) with dash(-) , if semicoln not present then data unchanged .
help me in this regards ....

Comment: don't write the the else part

Comment: the city field is dynamic how should i know the city field contains semicoln or not if it present then replace with dash otherwise keep data as it is . can you plz elaborate a little with query so that i can understand well

Comment: you are asking it to be done before inserting data or after inserting data?if its before inserting data, then you can use regexp in your server side script

Comment: already we have an table which i have mentioned earlier , need update query to the same , you got my question?

Comment: try this one `UPDATE user SET city = REPLACE(city, ',', '-');`

Answer (score 0):

Just handle that with another `case when ...` like so:

```
update user set gender = case when gender = 'Male' then 'Female' when gender = 'Female' then 'Male' else '' end
```

Comment: it's giving syntax error as u providing no data in else condition '' .

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1